# Android WebView crashes when clicking on a link

Tags: android, webview

I have some `WebView` widgets inside my `Activity`. I use `loadData()` to set the content, and this html contains a link. Some of my `WebViews` work okay, when I click the link, the web browser is started in a new window, but some make my app crash when I click on a link.

```
10-13 08:45:24.257: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.startActivity(ApplicationContext.java:627)
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:236)
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:185)
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:277)
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
10-13 08:45:24.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There seems to be a problem with the `Intent` that the `WebView` fires when I click the URL, but I have no control of this `Intent`, I think.

Does anybody have any idea?

I use this `AsyncTask` to set the content in the `WebView`, and it works fine:

```
public class SetAdTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    private Main main;
    private WebView webView;

    public SetAdTask(Main main, WebView webView){
        this.main = main;
        this.webView = webView;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Main.Log("onPreExecute()");                
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Main.Log("doInBackground()");                
        return main.getRestClient().getAdCode();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Main.Log("onPostExecute()");

        String html = "<html><head><title>ad</title></head><body>";
        html += "<div style=\"color:grey;font-size:12px;\">ADVERTISEMENT<br/>";
        html += result;
        html += "</body></html>";
        webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "latin-1");
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh, i found the problem.. I have initiated the webView with wrong context... i used viewView = new WebView(main.getApplicationContext()) ... Seems like the webview renders OK, with this context, but cant handle intents correctly... 

T

Comment: You can answer your own question, you know.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem was that my `webview` was initialized with wrong context...

i used:

`WebView w = new WebView(this.getApplicationContext())`

which crashes...

the correct `context` is the `activity` itself

`WebView w = new WebView(this)`

Comment: That did it, thanks so much! Although this issue only appeared on certain devices. Oh well, now it works for them all.

Comment: I had the same problem but with clickable links inside `ListView` items. This fixed it; thank you!

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to use an activity as your context, another (surprising) solution to this problem is to set up an empty `WebViewClient` for the `WebView`:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

It seems like an Android bug: according to the API you may use a context object to initialize a webview (but this might cause the bug you've mentioned).

Comment: If I could upvote you 100 more times, I would!  WebView with the application context is a crucial ability to maintain the internal state of the WebView across orientation changes.  Great find.

Comment: Great! Hallelujah!